# Remove all characters after the last special character javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following string.

```
var string  = "Welcome, to, this, site";
```

I would like to remove all characters after the last comma, so that the string becomes

```
var string  = "Welcome, to, this";
```

How do I go about it in Javascript? I have tried,

```
var string = "Welcome, to, this, site";
string = s.substring(0, string.indexOf(','));
```

but this removes all characters after the first comma.

Comment: Read about `String.prototype.split()`, `Array.prototype.pop()` and `Array.prototype.join()`.

Comment: `.lastIndexOf()` instead of `.indexOf()`, but make sure you check the result before using it. A `-1` probably won't give the result you're after.

Comment: did you try with the `lastIndexOf` method ?

Comment: thanks @squint.. Works.

Comment: I just did. @oliv37. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is lastIndexOf:

```
string = s.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf('?'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use split and splice to achieve the result as below.

```
var string  = "Welcome, to, this, site";
string = string.split(',')
string.splice(-1) //Take out the last element of array
var output = string.join(',')
console.log(output) //"welcome, to, this"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf(substring)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) method, you can just use that in replacement of `String.prototype.indexOf(substring)` :

```
var delimiter = ",";
if (inputString.includes(delimiter)) {
    result = inputString.substring(0, inputString.lastIndexOf(delimiter));
} else {
    result = inputString;
}
```

Alternatives would include [Madara Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha)'s suggestion :

```
var delimiter = ",";
var parts = inputString.split(delimiter);
if(parts.length > 0) { parts.pop(); }
result = parts.join(delimiter);
```

Or the use of regular expressions :

```
result = inputString.replace(/,[^,]*$/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var string  = "Welcome, to, this, site";
var ss = string.split(",");
var newstr = "";
for(var i=0;i<ss.length-1;i++){
  if (i == ss.length-2)
      newstr += ss[i];
  else
      newstr += ss[i]+", ";
}
alert(newstr);
```